# Bootstrap cards overlapping when performing a search

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have built out a page with cards using Bootstrap 4. I am able to search the cards and it returns only the ones with titles that match. the issue I am running into is 1. Two cards on the same row that match will overlap and 2. if it's on another row it doesn't move up to the first trow. I have tried a lot of different things, but have not been successful with making this work correctly. Looking for some help with what I need to do or at least where to look.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>"Brick Sets Coming Next"</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>"Brick Sets Coming Next"</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

      <div class="container-fluid-nav text-center">
        <h2>All the Pugs</h2>
      </div>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="text-center release-date">Pug List</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
       <input class="form-control" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </div>




      <!-- Row 1 of June 1st release -->
      <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-deck">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


          </div>

          <div class="no-results">No results found</div>



 <!-- Row 2 of June -->
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
               <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Little Pug</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
               <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Cool Pug</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
               <div class="card h-100" style="width: 21rem;">
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">cool dog</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

                    <div class="no-results">No results found</div>
        </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width


.body{
  margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: static;
    z-index: 999;
}

.card{

  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.card-columns{
  display: inline-block
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 999;
}

.card-deck{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.navbar-custom{
  background-color: #0B4949;
}


.container-fluid-nav{
  background-color: #448383;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn{
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

button.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}

h2{
  color: white;
}

img {

  width: 200px; /* You can set the dimensions to whatever you want */
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.release-date{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.no-results{
  display: none;
}
```

[After performing a search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A437i.png)

[The result I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjU8p.png)

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/grifftaur/uwro8my9/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call **uvs**   1 extra class to your column & same in jQuery  **$(".uvs").filter(function()**  please check below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".uvs").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width


.body{
  margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: static;
    z-index: 999;
}

.card{

  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.card-columns{
  display: inline-block
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 999;
}

.card-deck{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.navbar-custom{
  background-color: #0B4949;
}


.container-fluid-nav{
  background-color: #448383;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn{
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

button.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}

h2{
  color: white;
}

img {

  width: 200px; /* You can set the dimensions to whatever you want */
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.release-date{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.no-results{
  display: none;
}.card.h-100 {
    width: 100%;
}

.uvs{margin-bottom:30px;}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>"Brick Sets Coming Next"</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>"Brick Sets Coming Next"</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

      <div class="container-fluid-nav text-center">
        <h2>All the Pugs</h2>
      </div>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="text-center release-date">Pug List</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
       <input class="form-control" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      </div>




      <!-- Row 1 of June 1st release -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card-deck">
          <div class="row">
         
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
                  <div class="card h-100">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
                  <div class="card h-100">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
                  <div class="card h-100">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Super Pug</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                        <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                          <div class="mt-auto">
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                            <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                          </div>
                        <!--</div>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


      



 <!-- Row 2 of June -->
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
               <div class="card h-100">
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Little Pug</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
               <div class="card h-100">
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Cool Pug</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 uvs">
               <div class="card h-100" >
                   <div class="card-body">
                     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Mops_oct09_cropped2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                     <h5 class="card-title text-center">cool dog</h5>
                     <p class="card-text text-center">Pug Name: Derek<br />Weight: 15.6lbs<br />Height: 27.6 inches</p>
                     <!--<div class="row justify-content-center">-->
                       <div class="mt-auto">
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Buy</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Resell</a>
                         <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-secondary" disabled>Buy</a>
                       </div>
                     <!--</div>-->
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>

          </div>

          <div class="no-results">No results found</div>
        </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Umesh, I added the uvs into my JQuery and added in the uvs class to the columns, but cards are still overlapping each other. Middle card of the first row overlaps the card on the left still. Another search reduces results to 3 cards on row 1, but the one card on the second row does move up to the first row on the right and overlaps the middle card on the first row.

Comment: Snippet updated. I am removed width 21rem & .card.h-100 { width: 100%; } added in css. Need to remove inline css  style="width: 21rem;"  or replace it width 100% .

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. The issue I am running into now is some of the cards are squishing and becoming really thin after I perform a search. Some of the cards aren't maintaining their original size. It only happens when I perform a search.

Comment: Can you please check updated snippet. I made more changes for responsive.

Comment: I added in the CSS changes. Added in the uvs class to the CSS and the width to the .card class. Adding the 40% width  to the .card class squished all the cards on the page, but still having the same issue on search.

Comment: Can you please run code snippet. I made changes in HTMl code too.

Comment: Ran code snippet but it's giving an error. Error saying "jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript". What HTML did you change? Also, I included a JSFiddle link to my original post at the bottom of that post. It has the latest changes you have suggested except for the HTML ones you mention that I am not sure of. Hopefully that will help make it easier to trouble shoot.

Comment: For that error please replace these urls in header   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> instead of jquery & current bootstrap files js css

Comment: Added the urls to the header file but getting another error. I shared below.                                           
   {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 252,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: So your example worked perfectly. Here's what I can't figure out. I added in a different image and it breaks it. The card with the new image is squished when I search for it. It seems the image specifically is causing it to break.

Comment: Need to add same height width to all images.

Comment: I have CSS rules set for img. Is it that I need to set rules for the image specifically within the card?

Comment: Yes, if your images are various dimension, When we are using images for card need all images to be same height width for fit in card.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I appreciate you being patient and assisting.